# SQL Server - Set Date Format at insertion

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime

Does anyone know the correct syntax for this format: `dd-mmm-yyyy`. E.g. `04-DEC-2016`

Basic  Insert

```
INSERT INTO GoodTbl (GoodID, GoodDate)VALUES (7,'12-04-2016')
```

I did this and it worked

```
INSERT INTO GoodTbl (GoodID, GoodDate)VALUES (7,(CONVERT(DATETIME,'12-04-2016', 105)));
```

but 106 is the correct code. However using 106 (as shown) does not work.

```
INSERT INTO GoodTbl (GoodID, GoodDate)VALUES (7,(CONVERT(DATETIME,'12-04-2016', 106)));
```

Is there a different way to write this?

Comment: But 105 is correct. 106 is for `dd mon yyyy`, like `04 jul 2016`...

Comment: Is GoodDate a date field or string/varchar ?

Comment: I think formatting is responsibility of your UI code. For example in .NET formatting will be much easy task `date.ToString("dd-mmm-yyyy")`.

Comment: Correct insert would be `convert(datetime, '04-dec-2016', 106)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 2012+ you can use the format()

```
Select Format(GetDate(),'dd-MMM-yyyy')
```

Returns

```
03-Dec-2016
```

Another option is

```
Select Replace(convert(varchar(25),GetDate(),106),' ','-')
```

You realize that these conversions are string, so I am assuming the destination field is a string/varchar
Use VARCHAR instead of DateTime, then the following:

```
INSERT INTO GoodTbl (GoodID, GoodDate) 
VALUES (7,Replace(convert(varchar(25),cast('2016-12-04' as date),106),' ','-'))
```

Comment: Thanks. The goal is to display the date like this '04-DEC-2016'. And from what I can see 106 is the code for it. However, the synax I used does not work

Comment: Thanks @John Cappelleti. So what if the date is '04-Jun-2016', do I insert the date value into the parenthesis? Like (04-06-2016)

Comment: @Koda I would use the native format yyyy-mm-dd  (dashes are optional)

Comment: @Koda Still not clear if your GoodDate is a date field or string

Comment: The 04-JUN-2016 format is a requirement. That is why I am working to convert the date from the yyyy-mm-dd format. Its a Datetime field.

Comment: @Koda again is GoodDate a string or date field?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129696/discussion-between-koda-and-john-cappelletti).